# Send JSON by cURL always returns "No access"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, curl

I have this JSON data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
    data:"code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
```

To send this data to `http://www.example.com/test.php`, I have tried with this code:

```
<?php

//API URL
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'data' => 'code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b'
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

But, it always retuns `No access`.

What are wrong in my code? Can you help me to fix it?

---

> Sorry about my English, it is not good. If my my question is not clear, please comment below this question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the api information?

Comment: That brings up nothing. I'm talking about a webpage that tells you what URI to make your call to and what fields are required etc.

Comment: That's probably not the documentation link then.

Comment: It's not a problem with the code. The documentation would help me understand what the website expects as far as data and format.

Answer (score 0):

Without the documentation to look out the only thing I can suggest is to remove the data from the array and just make it key `code`.

```
<?php

//API URL
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';
$data = "?code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b"

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Ah, I kinda understand more. If it's a GET request you don't need half of those options. You just need to append the data onto the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

First check  `http://www.example.com/test.php`

Ajax system can't be used with full domain name.

so you should use `/test.php`

Then checking for an error that occurs in your site or target site.

Then the code becomes:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/test.php",
    data:"code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {   
        alert(data);
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    },
    error : function(data, textStatus, error){                  
        alert(data + "  : "+ textStatus);
    }
});
```