# How to send multiple "data" value to server, with JSON, by PHP?

Tags: php, json, curl

Many days ago, I read an interesting question about sending JSON data to webserver, at here: [Send JSON by cURL always returns "No access"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737205/send-json-by-curl-always-returns-no-access).

And, bellow is full code for answer:

```
<?php

//API URL
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';
$data = "?code=69Uy8&token=952b0f024c1e66a2a0f6f7759c2cdbfb";

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Now, I want to send multiple `data` values to `http://www.example.com/test.php`:

```
code=69Uy8&token=952b0f024c1e66a2a0f6f7759c2cdbfb
code=asf5C&token=1af76d050b0831537a5f8a4153290a6f
code=U3dhB&token=b2e909fcefaeef184c01f0ac6f284db8
code=I4pe5&token=34de7a8929842f80a44abd4af4a1f0b1
code=KaoBn&token=f0e953832394a69c6ebe2d518898584a
code=bgpTb&token=82b1eb052bb4b9473a695bc42942fe88
code=gBPuf&token=9e9ffe7707cc155aba665c2ac65bba62
code=e3uAx&token=edb90988db61e78b9167116e376e9a2c
code=fje60&token=a435c033a71b2244629de402c0a650a1
code=BTdhG&token=dff6f60bf424ce67d51f7d7270a8c1d0
```

How to send multiple `data` value to server, with JSON, by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

CURL support sending data arrays,
You can make your data array and send it to server with CURL
see this link
[Already asked in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596799/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-curl-post-requests)

You can send an JSON array, that will required to be decoded when server receives it, but with CURL you can send array, just use is_array() function to check whether requested parameters are array or single variable.

Comment: Provide more code to understand problem

Comment: Ok, now I think, does your server (test.php file) can process array in GET Request, I mean have you used, is_array() function to check whether uploaded data is single variable or an array() ? Also show test.php code